# Python unittest to detect running test under circleci

Tags: python, circleci

While in python code of a given unittest, I want to know if it is running under Circle CI or not. A [google search](https://www.google.com.vn/search?newwindow=1&rlz=1C5CHFA_enVN780VN780&biw=1227&bih=680&ei=jFuJWqWYCsfyvAS7-oWgDA&q=python%20detect%20running%20test%20under%20circleci&oq=python%20detect%20running%20test%20under%20circleci&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1.396414.523625.0.524005.3.2.1.0.0.0.113.113.0j1.2.0....0...1.2.64.psy-ab..0.3.256.6...138.L7MB3Gh_T3U) and [search on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Python%20unittest%20to%20detect%20running%20test%20under%20circleci) are not very helpful so I asked here.

How to tell we are running Python test under Circle CI or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CircleCI automatically [sets some environment variables](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/#circleci-environment-variable-descriptions) that you may use to determine this, specifically `CI` and `CIRCLECI`.

That said, I'm not sure why this would be important to your test.

Comment: Great thanks. It's important since I cannot get testing.redis pip package working with Circle CI while it works locally

Comment: An example would be testing a headed mode for a headless browser, for example.